# What is a Docker registry service connection?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

Following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp-on-container-linux?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml), `Docker registry service connection` is found in the following YAML. What is `Docker registry service connection` and where can it be found?

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: <Docker registry service connection>
  imageRepository: <Name of your image repository>
  containerRegistry: <Name of the Azure container registry>
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

- task: AzureWebAppContainer@1 # Add this at the end of your file
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<Azure service connection>'
    appName: '<Name of the container web app>'
    containers: $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
```

Answer (score 33):

A service connection is a connector to an external service (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)). A Docker registry service connection basically is a connector to a Docker registry. You can set it here:

[image: Azure Devops project home]
[image: Azure devops project settings]
[image: add service connection]

Answer (score 16):

mmking's answer covers the what part of the question, but not where can it be found.

After adding a "Docker Registry" service connection, select it from the list of service connections. The url will look something like:

```
https://your-org.visualstudio.com/YourProject/_settings/adminservices?resourceId=0b6c0705-9fbb-40ec-b629-95cd92856257
```

Take the resourceId from the query string, which is "0b6c0705-9fbb-40ec-b629-95cd92856257" in the above example, and use it as the dockerRegistryServiceConnection value.

Comment: This solved my issue together with above answer! Thanks dude

Comment: Perfect, this was the missing piece.

Answer (score 3):

One of the many connection types connection predefined by Microsoft; Read through their documentation: [Service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), you will definitely get a grasp that will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are three different container registry types : Docker Hub, Others and Azure Container Registry. I managed to connect to my Azure Container Registry - ACR - created for my subscription. I have created the ACR in Azure Portal via *Project Settings => Azure Pipelines : Service Connections* .
If you see the ACR you in the Azure Portal you find username and password via *Access Keys* tab.

Add service connection via : *Docker Registry* option. You can choose ACR also here as the type. Actually, I got it also working via the *Other* option in the dialog showing the connection to *Docker Registry*.

The Service Connection name must agree with the value of the containerRegistry in the YAML, if you rerun the Pipeline in Azure you should find the container registry.

[image: Setting up Docker Registry Service Connection]